# Adding a second heading to a table in an Outlook email

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I'm using the code below to add headings to a table I'm adding to an Outlook email.  I have a request to add a second row of headings in French.  I've tried a couple of things and I get the whole table highlighted in green.

Any help in pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.....

```
strBeforeRows = "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse:" & _
            "collapse;}</style></head><body>" & _
            "<table style=""width:60%""><tr>" & _
            "<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Rental Agreement # #</th>" & _
            "<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Citation #</th>" & _
            "<th bgcolor=""#11ed69"">Amount</th></tr>"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create `table` elements and you want to use header ([`th`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp)) cells then I normally make use of the [`thead`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp) element. I put the `<tr>` elements inside there.

At the moment we don't see a complete HTML snippet in your question so we can't give a thorough answer.